# REST: Update resource with unknown (server-generated) value

Tags: rest, http

I have a resource *foo* with the following structure:

`GET /foo/1` returns:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "server-key": "abcdef",
  "status": "expired"
}
```

Status can either be *active* or *expired*. If it is *expired* I want the server to generate a new one.

Normally I'd issue `PUT/PATCH foo/1` with the new key, but client doesn't know the key-generation algorithm.
I could also do a `POST foo/1/server-key` with no body, but that feels strange (I know this isn't very scientific reason though).

Any good ideas/patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when you've got expired entity just make POST call on /foo without any parameters and server should return new entity (and HTTP response code should be 201):

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "server-key": "xyz",
  "status": "active"
}
```

If some resourece is expired it is unconvinient to make it active again by PUT/PATCH request.

Comment: Your last remark is not correct. The semantics of your application should be opaque to the semantics of the PUT and PATCH methods. All these methods know is that the client is asking to replace or apply a diff to a resource.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would adopt is to set a null value to `server-key` and let the server deal with it, but I do that because it's a consistent behavior in my APIs for the server to fill missing values with defaults.

Other than that, a simple POST to the URI as suggested in the other answer is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use a `PUT`/`PATCH` method in your case to ask for generate a token if expired. Generally it's not really RESTful to put an action name within the resource path ;-)

I would see something like that:

- Get the element: `GET /foo/1`
- If the status is expired, ask for a new server key to be generated: `POST /foo/1`. In this case, this method will be used to execute an action to reinitialize the key on the server side

Using the method `PUT` corresponds to update the complete representation with a new one provided by the client. With the method `PATCH`, you will do a partial update of the representation.

Here is a link that could give you some hints about the way to design a Web API (RESTful service): https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry